# почему не могу получить data-id для экземпляра в цикле?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
var services = $('.service-auto1');
    
    
    for(var i = 0; i < services.length; i++){
        console.log ( services[i].data('id')); //TypeError: services[i].data is not a function
    }
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <article class="prod-li sectls service-auto1" data-id="1">
    </article>
    <article class="prod-li sectls service-auto1" data-id="2">
    </article>
    <article class="prod-li sectls service-auto1" data-id="3">
    </article>
```

Comment: без использования jquery: получение элементов `document.querySelectorAll('.service-auto1');` получение значения data атрибута `services[i].dataset['id']`

Comment: @Junior так вы же не используете jq... либо jq -> `$(services[i]).data('id')`, либо js -> `services[i].dataset.id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var services = $('.service-auto1');
services.each(function(){
  console.log ($(this).attr('data-id'));
})
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article class="prod-li sectls service-auto1" data-id="1">
</article>
<article class="prod-li sectls service-auto1" data-id="2">
</article>
<article class="prod-li sectls service-auto1" data-id="3">
</article>
```